# update image path stored laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I have a register method that store images in the public folder of the project and then store it's path into the item row on DB and it's working for now:

```
 public function salvar(Request $request){

   if ($request->hasFile('image')){

    $product = new Product();
    $id = Produto::max('id')+1;

    $file = request()->file('image');
    $directoryImg = $file->storeAs('images/'. $id , 'image.jpg');

    $produto->description= $request->description;
    $produto->cathegory = $request->cathegory;
    $produto->price = $request->price;
    $produto->image = $directoryImg;
    $produto->save();
   }
   else{
    $product = new Product();
    $product = $product->create($request->all());
   }

   \Session::flash('mensage_success', 'Done!');
   return Redirect::to('products/new');
}
```

The problem is that when I'm using another method for update the item register, all the informations I change goes to the database, except the image that is not being stored in the path and the path itself in the database. The field keep the value it had before the method execution:

```
public function update($id, Request $request){
    $productEdit = Product::find($id);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')){ 

    $file = request()->file('image');
    $directoryImg = $file->storeAs('images/' . $productEdit->id , 'image.jpg');

    $productEdit->image = $directoryImg;
    $productEdit->description = $request->description;
    $productEdit->cathegory = $request->cathegory;
    $productEdit->price = $request->price;

    $productEdit->save();

    } 
}

return Redirect::to('products/');
```

Can someone help me find what am I missing here?

Comment: $productEdit->save() instead of $produto

Comment: The $produto-save() was just a misspelling. In the original code its already $productEdit->save(). lol

Comment: The [edit] a question with more up-to-date codes.

Comment: `'images/' . $productEdit->id , 'image.jpg'` vs `'images/'. $id , 'image.jpg'` will always result in the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will normally keep the value the same, no? since the ID stays the same, which means the Image path will remain the same because the image name is `ID+image.jpg`.

And try to delete the old image before updating it:

```
File::delete(public_path('images/' . $productEdit->id , 'image.jpg'));
```